# How can I avoid jQuery conflicts between 2 plugins

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete plugin (`jquery.autocomplete.js`) and I am using jQuery carousel and also I am using the some of bootstrap components. But when I add the `bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery-1.11.3.min.js` the autocomplete plugin is not working. How can I get it working.?

Autocomplete is working fine from `jQuery 1.2.6 - New Wave Javascript`

Comment: jQuery's version 1.2.6 is very old one. Have you tried to use version 1.11.3 with new version of Autocomplete plugin?

Answer (score 2):

When you load your jQuery.x.x.js, it will overwrite the existing $ and jQuery vars. BUT it keeps a backup copy of them (in `_$` and `_jQuery`). 
Calling `noConflict`(true) you restore the situation as it was before your js inclusion!

`noConflict()` gives you the running instance (the last loaded), so you can work with you version in this way

Resuming:

- original page loads his "jquery.versionX.js"
- $ and jQuery belong to versionX
- you call your "jquery.versionY.js"
- now $ and jQuery belong to versionY, plus _$ and _jQuery that belongs to versionX
- `var my_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);`
- now `$` and `jQuery` belong to versionX, `_$` and `_jQuery` are probably null, and `my_jQuery` is versionY

If you want to revert back to a specific version add following JavaScript code in HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (jQuery.fn.jquery != "1.11.0")
        var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30101470/2025923